# Why XP visual styles are not working with ShowDialog or without MdiParent?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm confused as to how to ask the question efficiently.

It seems that I cannot get XP Visual Styles to work on my WinForms in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 if I use .ShowDialog() ***OR*** if I use .Show() without first setting .MdiParent.

For example, this code:

```
frmCheckRecon.MdiParent = frmMainParent
frmCheckRecon.Show()
```

or this code:

```
Dim l_dialog As frmCheckRecon
l_dialog = New frmCheckRecon
l_dialog.MdiParent = frmMainParent
l_dialog.Show()
```

gives me the correct XP visual style (blue soft window border and nice control buttons)

But this code:

```
' frmCheckRecon.MdiParent = frmMainParent   <-- commented out
frmCheckRecon.Show()
```

or this:

```
Dim l_dialog As frmCheckRecon
l_dialog = New frmCheckRecon    
' l_dialog.MdiParent = frmMainParent  <-- commented out
l_dialog.Show()
```

gives me NON-XP style window (gray hard window edges, ugly control icons on window title bar, etc)

Because I can't set .MdiParent property if I'm calling the form with .ShowDialog, using .ShowDialog always shows the non-XP (ugly) window style.

Maybe it's easy?  What am I missing?

Comment: do you mean `AERO` styles?  You are on windows 8.1

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.  Most of the windows in my app show the "Aero" style like I want, but the ones I reference above that are NOT what I want show more like the Windows 8.1 style (flat, gray title bar).  I can seemingly "force" the desired style (Aero) by setting the .MdiParent property when possible, but I want to understand what is going on and when using .ShowDialog() I can't set .MdiParent first so then what?

Comment: More info.  Running my compiled application on 2 different Windows 8.1 machines experience the problem I am having...however running on a Windows 7 machine works as expected.  Both .Show and .ShowDialog show the "Aero" style window frames on Windows 7, but .ShowDialog on Windows 8.1 show flat/square window frame style and .Show gives the desired Aero look.